# jQuery table of contents plugin that uses anchor names

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableofcontents

I'm looking for a jQuery table of contents plugin that uses given anchor names. The ones that I've found always generate they own anchor names leading to instable URIs like `somewhere#toc_1_4`. But for an anchor like this

```
<h2><a name="something-special">Something Special</a></h2>
```

I want an URI like `somewhere#something-special`.

Is there such a plugin?

Comment: maybe this would do it
https://github.com/dcneiner/TableOfContents

Comment: Looks like the plugin I was looking for. Would you move your comment to an answer?

Comment: done, i've placed it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this plugin:

- [Table of Contents jQuery Plugin](http://github.com/dcneiner/TableOfContents)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know such plugin but this can be easily done by yourself:

```
$('a[name]').each(function(i, v) {
    var e = $(v);
    if (e.text() != '') {
        $('#toc').append('<li><a href="#' + e.attr('name') + '">' + e.text() + '</a></li>');
    }
});
```

For each link, append a list item to your #toc (could be an ordered list):

```
<h1>Table of contents:</h1>
<ol id="toc"></ol>
```

You could also add something like:

```
<a name="something-special" data-toc="yes" data-title="Special topic">special</a>
```

and use the code:

```
$('a[name]').each(function(i, v) {
    var e = $(v);
    var t = e.data('title') || e.text();
    if (e.data('toc') == 'yes' && t.length > 0) {
        $('#toc').append('<li><a href="#' + e.attr('name') + '">' + t + '</a></li>');
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/27Ubt/1/

Comment: Instead of `$('a')`, you can do `$('a[name]')`

Comment: You should declare `e` and `t` with `var`, for not polluting the global namespace.